# jquery ajax callback variable scope (why are some in scope and others not)

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, jquery-callback

I'm a newbie to Javascript and jQuery and am puzzled by the following code and results.

Why is my golfer_name in scope, but my team_id not in scope?  And how do I fix it?
It appears to be the array, and the variables set equal to an array element that are not available in the call back.

jQuery code

```
function submit_pick( sender ) {
    var names = sender.attr('name').split('-');
    var team_id = names[0];
    var tournament_id = names[1];
    var pick_number = names[2];
    var golfer_id = sender.val();
    var golfer_name = sender.find("option:selected").text();
    var senders_parent = sender.parent().get(0);
    sender.remove();
    $(senders_parent).html('submitting pick...');
    jQuery("#testdiv").append("submit pick before ajax request: "+names+', '+team_id+', '+tournament_id+', '+pick_number+', '+golfer_id+', '+golfer_name+'<br />');
    jQuery.post(fantasy_golf.ajaxurl, 
                {'action' : 'insert_pick',
                 'team_id' : team_id,
                 'tournament_id' : tournament_id,
                 'pick_number' : pick_number,
                 'golfer_id' : golfer_id
                },
                function(response) {
                    if (response) {
                        jQuery("#testdiv").append("submit pick after response: "+names+', '+team_id+', '+tournament_id+', '+pick_number+', '+golfer_id+', '+golfer_name+'<br />');
                    }
                },
                'text'
     );
}
```

Results from the #testdiv

```
submit pick before ajax request: 10,2,1, 10, 2, 1, 22, Aaron Baddeley
submit pick after response: undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, 22, Aaron Baddeley
```

Comment: Are you sure, you don´t have typo in original code? The code seems ok to me.

Comment: What is the content of `response` ?

Comment: The original code contained additional lines after the `jQuery("#testdiv").append("submit pick after response...` once I commented those lines out my code as posted above works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it interesting that the commented out lines of code (which were not originally commented out) caused the above error even though they were after what I thought the problem line of code was.

I apologize for not having all extra lines of code commented out prior to my question,  I was in the midst of moving some code around and new I still needed to look at the code below there, I just never figured it would cause a problem above that point.

Thanks all who helped.

```
function submit_pick( sender ) {
    var names = sender.attr('name').split('-');
    jQuery("#testdiv").append(sender.attr('name')+"<br />");
    var team_id = names[0];
    var tournament_id = names[1];
    var pick_number = names[2];
    var golfer_id = sender.val();
    var golfer_name = sender.find("option:selected").text();
    var senders_parent = sender.parent().get(0);
    sender.remove();
    $(senders_parent).html('submitting pick...');
    jQuery("#testdiv").append("submit pick before ajax request: "+names+', '+team_id+', '+tournament_id+', '+pick_number+', '+golfer_id+', '+golfer_name+'<br />');
    jQuery.post(fantasy_golf.ajaxurl, 
                {'action' : 'insert_pick',
                 'team_id' : team_id,
                 'tournament_id' : tournament_id, 
                 'pick_number' : pick_number,
                 'golfer_id' : golfer_id 
                },
                function(response) {
                    if (response) {
                        jQuery("#testdiv").append("submit pick after response: "+names+', '+team_id+', '+tournament_id+', '+pick_number+', '+golfer_id+', '+golfer_name+'<br />');
//                            var names = $this.attr('id').split('-');
//                            var pick_id = names[1];
//                            var team_id = names[2];
//                            var tournament_id = names[3];
//                            var pick_number = names[4];
                    }
                },
                'text'
    );
}
```